# mongo db crosss collection query

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections in MongoDB, one is placements and the other is tids.

Placements collection has program_id, placement_id, tids collection has placement_id and tid_id.

I want be able to find all placements with program_id as 3,5 and then find all the tid_id in tids collection with those placement_id, so in SQL it would be:

```
select tids.tid_id 
from tids 
inner join placements 
where tids.placement_id = placements.placement_id
and placements.program_id = 3 or 5
```

It says MongoDB doesn't support join, so is it even possible to do a query like this?

Comment: need to query twice in mongodb, one on placements, one on tids.

Comment: you can only query at the collection level. depending on the data, it might be easier to load the smaller of the collections in memory and then begin querying in a coding language of your choice.

Comment: the problem is there are millions of records in both collections, i use mongoDB java clients, using loops is really slow and memory consuming, if i can delegate mongdb query that would be much efficient

Comment: sounds like your schema doesn't match your use case very well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I can't offer any magic, there's no join.

1) But as to your note about "millions of records and slow loops", you can use indices, it shouldn't be that slow: 
(a) On Placements collection - put an index of program_id, so you can easily search by it
(b) Once extracting those placements, make a java list of their placementIds
(c) On tids collecton - put an index of placementIds, and run an $in query (with placementIds extraced above)

2) Alternatively, please consider Asya Kamsky's comment above, in mongo its a bit of a common practice to denormalize/aggregate data, e.g. if its 1:many (not many:many) than perhaps an aggregated 'placement' document like
    placement:{
      id:..
      data...
      tids:[
         {tid 1 info...},
         {tid 2 info...},
      ]
}
.Beware: denormalized data might be hard to maintain, it's one of the main criticisms against mongo and its design patterns, but still it has to be brought up for careful consideration.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo, as you have mentioned, you cannot do a join and as a result, you cannot get the output in one single query. The query is executed only on single collection. The only possible way is to fetch it separately from both the collection and then merge it in your code.